# PopupMenu and JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpopupmenu

I try to create a popup menu that contains a JTable and that can show other popup menu.  The JTable has mouse listener so that when a menu item has other item to show a new JPopupMenu is created with a JTable inside and so on.
The problem I have is that there is only one popup menu showing at a time.  Every time a menu from my JTable popup menu has to show another popup menu, the previous popup disappear.

Comment: Swing only supports one `JPopupMenu` at a time

Comment: agreed long time registred as bug, you can to replace JPupup with un_decorated JDialog,

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll try with JDialog.